# Upgrading MySQL 5.1 to 5.7 : binary or SQL files?

Tags: mysql

I'm going to upgrade from `5.1` to `5.7` but the database size is about `22 GB`.

So instead of exporting then importing some `SQL` files, I'm wondering if copying the binary files themselves `(frm myd myi)` is ok.

Are there any side effects doing this ?

Comment: I'm assuming your tables are MyISAM based on the extensions you listed. Are they all exlcusively? Copying InnoDB binaries can be a bit messier.

Comment: yes, all MyISAM

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming. You may get more support from the DBAs, than from developers here on SO.